# Sticky header md-table-container angular js material design

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, material-design, angular-material

table-container to display records. I have a requirement, when table reaches to top of the screen it's header stick to top. Please guide me to implement this requirement.

For example see this link
http://angular-data-grid.github.io/demo/fixed-header/angular-md-grid.html#!?page=1&itemsPerPage=75

Thank you,
Java4you.

Answer (score 4):

Using the Angular Material table, adding the following to the .scss file for the containing component will now achieve this, but not in IE unfortunately:

```
.mat-header-row {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: inherit;
}
```

See [this](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/9143) for discussion.

Comment: It was perfect, I just add you might increase z-index too, as mat-icons will be one the top of the mat-row-header