# Angular 6 Material Data Table with Fixed Header and Paginator

Tags: angular, angular-material

How to make the Header of Data Table component fixed to the top, and the Paginator fixed to the bottom?

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">

    <table mat-table #itemsTable [dataSource]="dataSource" class="items-list">

        <ng-container matColumnDef="position">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> No. </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.position}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="name">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Name </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.name}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="weight">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Weight </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.weight}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <ng-container matColumnDef="symbol">
            <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Symbol </th>
            <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.symbol}} </td>
        </ng-container>

        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="this.componentsDataService.displayedColumns"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: this.componentsDataService.displayedColumns;" (click)="onRowClicked(row)"></tr>
    </table>

    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[50, 100, 250]" showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>

</div>
```

I tried adding `sticky` to the `<tr mat-header-row>` from the docs, but it doesn't work.

My imports in .ts file:

```
 import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, Input, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
 import { TabsDataService } from 'src/app/services/tabs-data.service';
 import { ComponentsDataService } from 'src/app/services/components-data.service';
 import { MatPaginator, MatTableDataSource, MatTable, MatTableModule } from '@angular/material';
```

Comment: What have you tried already? How is your code structured ?

Comment: @chiril.sarajiu i have added my code

Comment: That is not all of your relevant code, where is the TS where you import the required module?

Comment: stackoverflow in nutshell

Comment: why the hell you need my ts file? everything works fine i just want sticky header

Comment: Because it might say why the sticky doesn't work, missed module or some such. But entire ts files aren't  needed, only relevant portions of them.

Comment: @fredrik i have added my ts imports

Comment: When you way stick, is ut togs you're after? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46468665/sticky-header-md-table-conta

Comment: @fredrik it doesn't work for me

Answer (score 133, accepted):

I found in the examples on the [material site](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#sticky-rows-and-columns) that the header can be fixed by adding sticky to the matHeaderRowDef:

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true">
```

For the paginator i added a class to mat-paginator:

```
<mat-paginator ...
                class="mat-paginator-sticky">
```

with a class based on the answer in the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46468665/sticky-header-md-table-container-angular-js-material-design) @frederik provided in the comments

```
.mat-paginator-sticky {
  bottom: 0px;
  position: sticky;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Comment: OK this helped me a lot! Thanks! Before I was using `mat-card` with `mat-card-titel`, `mat-card-content` (containing the table) and `mat-card-footer` (containing the paginator) to achieve some similar design. But I do prefer this solution way more.

Comment: Note: My row actually looks like: `<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>`

Answer (score 23):

As per Material 8.1

1. For the sticky header we need to give a sticky values as shown in many answers here
2. For the sticky paginator or bottom fixed paginator.

We can wrap the table inside a div with max-height or height CSS Property and put the paninator outside that div.

Html Code sample.

```
 <div class="mat-elevation-z2">
    <div class="table-container">

      <!--- List of column definitions here --->
      <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
      </table>

    </div>
    <mat-paginator [pageSize]="25" [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 15, 25, 100]"></mat-paginator>
 </div>
```

CSS

```
  table {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .table-container {
    max-height: calc(100vh - 155px); // or height: calc(100vh - 155px); depending on your need  change
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

Comment: This is one of the best solutions.
I created a example by also set first column to sticky: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-p6zdti

Comment: This is good if you want your whole table to be essentially a fixed height, which in most cases, I think acts most naturally. You might want to scroll down a list by scrolling your whole screen, but I think users expect tables (esp. with paginators) to have a fixed size.

Answer (score 14):

Try to update angular material in your project because the sticky attribute was added in 6.2.3.

Comment: I don't think this should be the best answer.  Many below work without making you upgrade.

Comment: @Farasi78 i agree but I said that because he used the sticky attribute from the doc at first

Answer (score 5):

The below css worked for me:

```
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
.mat-header-row{
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
  background: white;
  }
```

Comment: I don't know what is wrong, but when I try to pin header by means of css                
  .mat-header-row{
  position: sticky;                                                                                                                  it doesn't work. Only specifying explicitly in html sticky: true helps

Comment: @M.Laida It shouldn't, as `sticky` position is not in IE11.

Answer (score 4):

I too had this problem. I created a div of fixed size and then kept the table inside div. This should solve your issue.

```
<div style="height: 300px; overflow: auto">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]=dataSource>
        <!--Your table entries here -->
        . 
        .
        .
        .
        <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></tr>
        <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 2):

You can use a normal sticky `mat-footer-row` with `colspan` and put the paginator inside:

```html
<table mat-table>
   ...

    <ng-container matColumnDef="paginator">
        <td mat-footer-cell *matFooterCellDef [colSpan]="displayedColumns.length">
            <mat-paginator ...></mat-paginator>
        </td>
    </ng-container>

    <tr mat-footer-row *matFooterRowDef="['paginator']; sticky: true"></tr>
</table>
```

And use some style like this, to make it more appealing to eye:

```css
.mat-row:last-child td {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.mat-footer-row:first-child td {
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
}

.mat-footer-cell .mat-paginator {
  margin-left: -24px;
  margin-right: -24px;
}
```

Comment: This is too hacky, We can wrap the table inside a div with max-height or height CSS Property, the issue will be solved.

Comment: This was the only solution that I could get working with a variable-height window, without having to do a vh calculation. Might be hacky but at least it does what I want!

Answer (score 1):

`<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true">`

To show the scrollbar only in table body

```
::ng-deep {
    tbody {
      display: block;
      overflow: auto;
      height: 65vh;
      width: 100%;
    }

    thead, tbody tr {
      display: table;
      width: 100%;
      table-layout: fixed;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that **my mistake** was to use

```
<mat-header-cell ...
<mat-cell ...
```

instead of

```
<th mat-header-cell ...
<td mat-cell
```