# How to make only table content scrollable in a dialog? - Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an [Angular Material Dialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) which contains [Material Table](https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview). I would like to make the table content scrollable (not even the table header). By default, the dialog's content is scrollable which is not what I want. Please see the example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-form-7e1zao?file=app%2Fdialog.component.html)

Comment: Same question has answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51709280/angular-6-material-data-table-with-fixed-header-and-paginator

Comment: @YogendraChauhan I could make the content scrollable but it's a problem when I have the table in a dialog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be easily achieved by using flex:

Add `dialog.component.scss` file to styleUrls of your component with the following rules:

```
:host,
form  {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
}

form,
.table-body {
  flex: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
```

Add sticky: true to your table header:

```
*matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-form-hah5kt?file=app%2Fdialog.component.html)**

Comment: Thanks @yurzui .. But it's problem if there are elements before the table which I don't want to scroll.

Comment: Please check the sample in the question again. Thanks for checking.

Comment: I updated my demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-form-hah5kt?file=app%2Fdialog.component.scss

Comment: Wish I could upvote your answer more than once. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-table-with-form-xuayxj

Just add this style on your table `max-height: 200px;overflow:auto;` & create mat header row sticky like this:

```
<mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns; sticky: true"></mat-header-row>
```